# CSS width: auto and max-width: 100% not working in concert

Tags: css

I have an `img` that's located in the `td` of a table.  All of the images have been large enough to overflow the `td` so I set the `width: 100%` so it would scale the image to fit.  I've now noticed that there are occasionally smaller images that would not overflow the `td`, but end up being stretched to fit based on my `width: 100%` style.  What I would like is to have the image it's original size unless it would overflow its container in which case I want it to be scaled to fit.

To accomplish this, I thought I only had to apply these styles:

```
table img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

The `width: auto` works, but it doesn't seem like the `max-width: 100%` does.   Does it have to do with the position of the `img` or the `img`'s container?

EDIT: It looks like this:
[image]

You can see it doesn't actually overflow outside the `td`, but I've selected the image in Firebug so you can see the image does go beyond where I want it.

Comment: `table img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}` <-- use this

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  I've added a screenshot to show.

Comment: `width`, `max-width` works here: http://jsfiddle.net/L5nf2/. Does your code differ much from this? Can you reproduce your issue so we can see the code?

Comment: I think it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L5nf2/2/.  I expect the larger image to scale to size where the right edge is where the red background `td` ends.

Comment: It's behaving exactly as it should. I think you have a misunderstanding of how it works. The image will only expand to the size of its direct parent. Since you have padding on the right div, the table elements will expand to fill the remaining space. The images will only expand to fill the space of the td.

Comment: That jsfiddle was a quick attempt at recreating the situation.  My actual app's markup and css is more complex and I guess I was unable to recreate the issue in the example.